# Java/Processing - Moving object in an even line from node to node

Tags: java, processing

My title probably does not make much sense which is why I am having a bit of an issue googling my problem.

I am trying to move a shape on the screen from one set of X/Y coordinates to another in a direct line.
So for example,

This is the class method for setting the new target direction.

```java
void setTargetPosition(int targetX, int targetY) {
    xTar = targetX;
    yTar = targetY;
        
    if (xPos > xTar) 
        xDir = -1; 
    else
        xDir = 1;
        
    if (yPos > yTar)
        yDir = -1; 
    else
        xDir = 1;
}
```

This would set the Direction of the X/Y variables and the following code would move the player on the screen.

```java
void drawPlayer() {
        
    fill(circleColour);
    circle(xPos,yPos,35);

    //stops player from moving once target destination has been reached
    if (xPos == xTar) 
        xDir = 0; 
        
    if (yPos == yTar)
        yDir = 0;
        
    xPos += xDir;
    yPos += yDir;
}
```

The above code does work mostly as intended but I need to find a way to proportionally change the X/Y coordinate so that it's more of a 'direct line' to the destination.

Sorry if this does not make sense. I don't know the right terms to use.

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111799/movement-with-vector-math - maybe this might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use floating point values for the computation of the movement rather than integral values:

```java
float xTar;
float yTar;
float xPos;
float yPos;
```

`setTargetPosition` just set `xTar` and `yTar`:

```java
void setTargetPosition(float targetX, float targetY) {
    xTar = targetX;
    yTar = targetY;
}
```

In `drawPlayer` you have to compute the direction vector ([`PVector`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html)) from the objects position to the target:

```java
PVector dir = new PVector(xTar - xPos, yTar - yPos);
```

if the length of the vector ([`mag()`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_mag_.html)) is greater than 0, the you have to move the object:

```java
if (dir.mag() > 0.0) {
    // [...]
}
```

If you have to move the object, then compute the [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) by [`normalize()`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_normalize_.html). Note, the length of a unit vector is 1. Multiply the vector by a certain speed by [`mult()`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_mult_.html). This scales the vector to a certain length. Ensure that the length of the vector is not greater than the distance to the object (`min(speed, dir.mag())`). Finally add the components of the vector to the position of the object:

```java
dir.normalize();
dir.mult(min(speed, dir.mag()));

xPos += dir.x;
yPos += dir.y;
```

See the example:

[image]

```java
class Player {
  
    float xTar;
    float yTar;
    float xPos;
    float yPos;
    color circleColour = color(255, 0, 0);
    
    Player(float x, float y)
    {
      xTar = xPos = x;
      yTar = yPos = y;
    }
  
    void setTargetPosition(float targetX, float targetY) {
        xTar = targetX;
        yTar = targetY;
    }
    
    void drawPlayer() {
    
        fill(circleColour);
        circle(xPos,yPos,35);
    
        float speed = 2.0;    
        PVector dir = new PVector(xTar - xPos, yTar - yPos);
        
        if (dir.mag() > 0.0) {
            dir.normalize();
            dir.mult(min(speed, dir.mag()));
            
            xPos += dir.x;
            yPos += dir.y;
        }
    }
}

Player player;

void setup() {

   size(500, 500);
   player = new Player(width/2, height/2);
}

void draw() {
    background(255);
    player.drawPlayer();
}

void mousePressed() {
    player.setTargetPosition(mouseX, mouseY);
}
```